# Show TIMEDIFF in set format

Tags: php, mysql

```
$arr = explode(':', $row['diff']);
echo "$arr[0] minutes, $arr[1] seconds";
```

Array is outputting: `Array00 hours, 20 minutes`, when it should be outputting: `[x] hours, [x] minutes`. ONLY IF there are >= 1 hour

This is in the SQL:

```
TIMEDIFF(now(), listDT) as diff
```

Is there someway to show, just minutes, if the output is like 0 hours, 22 minutes? Why is Array in front? Can I remove it? How?

---

**Updated**

```
foreach($result as $row)
        { 

        echo "<div class='listing'>";
            print $row['uUName'] . '</strong><br />' .
            '<strong>' . $row['listTitle'] . '</strong><br />' .
            $arr = explode(':', $row['diff']);
            echo "{$arr[0]} minutes, {$arr[1]} seconds";
        echo "</div>";
        }
```

This STILL outputs: `Array00 hours, 31 minutes` for example. How do I get it to look like:

```
00 hours, 31 minutes
```

or

(ideally, if hours is 0) `31 minutes`

Comment: It is not possible for your output to have the word `hours`, it is nowhere in your code....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add braces so that your array vars can be properly interpreted. Like this:

```
echo "{$arr[0]} minutes, {$arr[1]} seconds";
```

ETA

leaving out the parts that equal zero means looping through the array and asking if the array needs to be output or not.

```
$map=array_combine(array('hours','minutes','seconds'),$arr);//so each part knows its name
$filtred=array_filter($map);//get rid of 0 values
foreach($filtred as $name=>$num){
  echo "$num $name ";
}
```

Comment: see updated please. I need to not have array in the front, and if hr is 0, then don't show it and just show minutes. How do I do that

Comment: I dont understand what your doing here. Can you see my updated code and possibly help out? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
sscanf($row['diff'], '%i:%i:%i', $hour, $min, $sec);
echo "$hour hours, $min minutes, $sec seconds";
```

[**DOC**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sscanf.php)
[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/Wik6cg01)

Comment: see updated please. I need to not have array in the front, and if hr is 0, then don't show it and just show minutes. How do I do that? using sscanf() seems to be messing it up when i implement this.

Comment: How do I assign $row['diff'] to the current time, like I am currently doing in MYSQL: `TIMEDIFF(now(), listDT) as diff`  ?

Comment: heh? I have no idea what you mean

Comment: Please see above. If I want to use your code, it outputs: `30 hours, 54 minutes, 30 seconds`  . It seems to be adding a day to the amount and NOT counting from today. How do I set `$row['diff']` to how it is setup above using `SELECT uUName, listTitle, TIMEDIFF(now(), listDT) as diff` in the SQL. Using a variable like `$difftime = $row['diff']` . Following me?

Comment: @Jay not at all.... go here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php you might get more help

Comment: I dont have enough rep to talk in there

Answer (score 0):

Try `echo "{$arr[0]} minutes, {$arr[1]} seconds";` Arrays inside double quotes need curly braces around them.